# How to set up LightDM in Arch Linux?

Tags: archlinux, gui

I have been running through methods of installing and configuring lightdm as according to the Arch Wiki (In order to try out the available cinnamon desktop), but I have had no luck in getting the program running.

I had installed the 'Lightdm','lightdm-gtk3-greeter', and 'cinnamon ' packages to start with.

After all configuration, I get this:

[FAILED] Failed to start light display manager.
See 'systemctl status Lightdm.service' for details.
Stopping light display manager...
[OK] Stopped light display manager.
Starting light display manager..

And then after that, the process repeats, until the last copy ends with:

[OK] reached target graphical interface

And the screen freezes.

Help?

Comment: As mentioned in your error message, you have to check the return of the `systemctl status lightdm.service` command and also the `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` file

Comment: @Nicolas The problem that seems to be going is this: `DEBUG: Seat: creating greeter session DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration lightdm-gtk3-greeter  DEBUG: Seat: Failed to create Greeter session.`  To start, what might that mean? (My guesses are that the greeter may need configuration, or the lightdm configuration is missing options, so on)

Comment: Could you check that you have a `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` file with the good access rights.

Answer (score 1):

I too had `lighdm`, `lightdm-gtk3-greeter`, and `cinnamon` installed and experienced the same errors.

In my case, I solved this by commenting out a line in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` I had added to enable the gtk3-greeter:

```
#greeter-session=lightdm-gtk3-greeter
```

After rebooting, lightdm started successfully. I am not sure what greeter is in use when none is specified in the config, but I am guessing it is not the gtk3-greeter.